# NSComparator in Separate File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have a sorting comparator which I need to use in a few different ViewControllers so I'm trying to keep it in a separate file. I've read I should be able to put the sorting block in a separate file, but which ever method I try I seem to get "unrecognized selector sent to instance". The code I have is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NSComparator (^IntBlock)(id obj1, id obj2);

@interface Utils : NSObject {
    NSComparator SortObjNameComparer;
    NSComparator SortObjPriceComparer;
}
@property (readwrite, copy) NSComparator SortObjNameComparer;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSComparator SortObjPriceComparer;
```

To sort this I'm using

```
Utils *comp = [[Utils alloc] init];
if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    self.productArray = [self.productArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:[comp SortObjNameComparer] context:nil];   //EXC_BAD_ACCESS     
} else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    self.productArray = [self.productArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:[Utils SortObjPriceComparer]];// EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: How about sortedArrayUsingFunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to create a C function that returns a block. That way you can create this block wherever you like:

e.g

**MyComparator.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSComparator CreateObjNameComparer(void);
NSComparator CreateObjPriceComparer(void);
```

**MyComparator.m**

```
#import MyComparator.h

NSComparator CreateObjNameComparer(void) {
    NSComparator myComparator = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // Your definition here
    };
    return Block_copy(myComparator);
}

NSComparator CreateObjPriceComparer(void) {
    NSComparator myComparator = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // Your definition here
    };
    return Block_copy(myComparator);
}
```

And then all you need to do it use these is to import the header and use it as:

```
NSComparator nameComparator = CreateObjNameComparor();
// Use the block
Block_release(nameComparator);
```

Saves having to go through the whole Object creation and property route.

Note that I'm using the `Create` naming convention to remind me that I have to release the object myself when I'm done with it.

Comment: This looks promising. I can give it a go tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you declaring IntBlock as a block that returns an NSComparator, I do not believe you will need that at all. Also blocks are allocated on the stack by default so make sure when you initialize the properties you do so correctly. If you post the initialization of your block it would help to answer your question but your implementation should look similar to this.

```
-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        //Make sure you use self.
        self.SortObjNameComparer = ^(id obj1, id obj2){ return NSOrderedSame; };
        self.SortObjPriceComparer = ^(id obj1, id obj2){ return NSOrderedSame; };
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dellaoc
{
    Block_release(SortObjNameComparer);
    Block_release(SortObjPriceComparer);

    [super dealloc];
}
```